# Is it possible to have a ZipOutputstream or GZIPOutputStream in Android that can be incrementally added to?

Tags: java, android, zip, gzip

My app creates a large amount of output, but only over a long time. Each time there is new output to add it is just a string (a few hundred bytes worth).

It would simplify my code considerably if I could add incrementally (i.e. append) to a pre-existing GZIP (or Zip) file. Is this even possible (in Java, specifically)?

I am looking for a solution that will create a file that can be opened by 3rd party apps.

I realize I can decompress the file, add the additional text and compress it again as a new blob.

Thanks

PVS

Comment: The Zip and GZip file formats do not allow simultaneous read write access.

Comment: You can append to a GZipOutputStream: the [format](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-gzip.html) permits it. But applications that read files that are still being written by other parts of the application are inherently poorly designed, and probably poorly implemented. It's rather difficult to get this right, and particularly to cope correctly with various error cases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  See this example in C in the examples directory of the zlib distribution: [gzlog.h](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/gzlog.h) and [gzlog.c](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/gzlog.c).  It does exactly that, allowing you to append short pieces of data to a gzip file.  It does so efficiently, by not compressing the additions until a threshold is reached, and then compressing what hasn't been compressed so far.  After each addition, the gzip file contains the addition and is a valid gzip file.  The code also protects against system crashes in the middle of an append operation, recovering the file on the next append operation.

Though allowed by the format, this code does not simply concatenate short gzip streams.  That would result in very poor compression.